# Missing Oauth module from core

Tags: magento-1.7, oauth, ce-1.7.0.0

I've been asked to look at a store with version 1.7.0.0 reported in the footer of the admin. The store received a patch notification and I am attempting to apply the patch and get messages about missing files. Indeed, I check for files at:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Oauth
```

Those files are not there. Suspicious, I checked the database for entries in `core_resource` and that the tables `oauth_token`, `oauth_nonce`, and `oauth_consumer` exist. They did not, suggesting that the `Oauth` module was never loaded with this install. Additionally, frontend and admin layout files `oauth.xml` do not exist.

Checking the release at https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.7 as well as the download from the official archive, this module should be included.

**Does this essentially mean the store is running a Magento release that was *prior* to 1.7.0.0 despite the version reported in admin?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible the Magento instance you are working on was upgraded from and earlier version and the missing files may have been missed.

Easy way to check is `grep -r "oauth" ./*` and see if there are any other references to oauth. Or if the project is versioned, you could check history and compare previous commits.

Comment: Yeah, I found no other evidence of Oauth ever existing. Digging deeper, I'm seeing 1.6.1 reported several places (`Mage_Core`) so I am assuming at this point a failed Magento Connect upgrade occurred. I'm guessing this happened maybe because of bad file permissions or a disallowed php method in WHM/CPanel or something.